# SQL Server - How to know which tables are used and which are not?

Tags: sql-server-2017, table

I have a database that has 225 tables in it

What is the best way to find out / log which tables are used, and which are not ?

I would like to see something similar to below:

```
Table 1 - select 2222 times, insert 0 times, update 3 times, delete 0 times  
Table 2 - select 1 times, insert 50 times, update 0 times, delete 5 times
```

Or in a below format:

```
Table 1 - select 2222  
Table 1 - update 0  
Table 2 - select 1  
Table 2 - insert 50  
Table 2 - delete 5
```

Comment: You can glean some of this information from `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`, which will reflect usage since the instance was last started.

Comment: This link https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tracking-table-usage-and-identifying-unused-objects shows some other methods as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT t.name AS [TableName],
       fi.page_count AS [Pages],
       fi.record_count AS [Rows],
       CAST(fi.avg_record_size_in_bytes AS int) AS [AverageRecordBytes],
       CAST(fi.avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS int) AS [AverageFragmentationPercent],
       SUM(iop.leaf_insert_count) AS [Inserts],
       SUM(iop.leaf_delete_count) AS [Deletes],
       SUM(iop.leaf_update_count) AS [Updates],
       SUM(iop.row_lock_count) AS [RowLocks],
       SUM(iop.page_lock_count) AS [PageLocks]
  FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL) AS iop
  JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON iop.index_id = i.index_id AND
                           iop.object_id = i.object_id
  JOIN sys.tables AS t ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND
                          i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'HEAP')
  JOIN sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED') AS fi ON fi.object_id=CAST(t.object_id AS int) AND
                                                                                     fi.index_id=CAST(i.index_id AS int)
  GROUP BY t.name, fi.page_count, fi.record_count, fi.avg_record_size_in_bytes, fi.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
  ORDER BY [RowLocks] desc
```

Remarks:
[sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> (How the Counters in the Metadata Cache Are Reset
>
> The data returned by sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats exists only as
>   long as the metadata cache object that represents the heap or index is
>   available. This data is neither persistent nor transactionally
>   consistent. This means you cannot use these counters to determine
>   whether an index has been used or not, or when the index was last
>   used. For information about this, see sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.
>
> The values for each column are set to zero whenever the metadata for
>   the heap or index is brought into the metadata cache and statistics
>   are accumulated until the cache object is removed from the metadata
>   cache. Therefore, an active heap or index will likely always have its
>   metadata in the cache, and the cumulative counts may reflect activity
>   since the instance of SQL Server was last started. The metadata for a
>   less active heap or index will move in and out of the cache as it is
>   used. As a result, it may or may not have values available. Dropping
>   an index will cause the corresponding statistics to be removed from
>   memory and no longer be reported by the function. Other DDL operations
>   against the index may cause the value of the statistics to be reset to
>   zero.)

Comment: This is useful! Row_lock_count / and page_lock_count - these are combined locks from all operations "select/insert/delete/update", right ?

Comment: one more question - one of my tables shows 2 "range scans" (I added this column into your query) but 0 inserts/updates/deletes/row+page locks. How can it be that "range scans" did not apply any locks ?