# Operational stats mention the same table twice, what does this mean?

Tags: sql-server, statistics, troubleshooting

While investigating why my application mentions deadlocking, I fell upon [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258864), whose answer mentions an SQL query, showing operational logs. However, the results of that query contain the same tablename twice, for some tables.

How should I interpret that result?

Hereby the mentioned SQL query:

```
SELECT t.name AS [TableName],
   fi.page_count AS [Pages],
   fi.record_count AS [Rows],
   CAST(fi.avg_record_size_in_bytes AS int) AS [AverageRecordBytes],
   CAST(fi.avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS int) AS [AverageFragmentationPercent],
   SUM(iop.leaf_insert_count) AS [Inserts],
   SUM(iop.leaf_delete_count) AS [Deletes],
   SUM(iop.leaf_update_count) AS [Updates],
   SUM(iop.row_lock_count) AS [RowLocks],
   SUM(iop.page_lock_count) AS [PageLocks]
FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL) AS iop
JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON iop.index_id = i.index_id AND
                       iop.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND
                      i.type_desc IN ('CLUSTERED', 'HEAP')
JOIN sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED') AS fi ON fi.object_id=CAST(t.object_id AS int) AND
                                                                                 fi.index_id=CAST(i.index_id AS int)
GROUP BY t.name, fi.page_count, fi.record_count, fi.avg_record_size_in_bytes, fi.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
ORDER BY [RowLocks] desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it may return the same `TableName` twice (or more), because the query you're using is looking at system views that return information about indexes, and one table can have multiple indexes on it.

[`sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Returns current lower-level I/O, locking, latching, and access method activity for each partition of a table or **index** in the database.

[`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Returns size and fragmentation information for the data and **indexes** of the specified table or view in SQL Server. For an index, **one row is returned for each level of the B-tree** in each partition. For a heap, one row is returned for the IN_ROW_DATA allocation unit of each partition. For large object (LOB) data, one row is returned for the LOB_DATA allocation unit of each partition. If row-overflow data exists in the table, one row is returned for the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit in each partition.

Comment: I have replaced `SELECT t.name` by `SELECT i.name, t.name` and `GROUP BY t.name` by `GROUP BY i.name, t.name` and I still have double entries (for the same index name and table name). Is it still normal?

Comment: @Dominique notice I highlighted this "*one row is returned for each level of the B-tree in each partition*" in the second paragraph I quoted. Your query not only returns one row per index per table, but also per level of the B-Tree in each of those indexes. Not sure why you'd want to group though, that defeats the purpose of this data.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was looking for a way to see the usage and locks of some tables in order to solve a deadlock situation, but I believe this SQL query can't be used for that, right?

Comment: @Dominique No I don't believe so. I saw your other question about deadlocks too. The easiest way to understand what's going on is by profiling the database with a tool, either [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) (for a quick overview of what's blocking / being blocked) or the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) itself (more complex). But that means you'd need access to your customer's SQL Server instance or they'd need to provide repeatable steps to recreate the deadlock / blocking on your end.